# How to write test case for non instance method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, frontend

Help on writing React test case

```
import {getEvent} from './utility'
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     ......
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     ....
     this.addEventListeners();
  }

  addEventListeners() {
     const targetEvent = getEvent() === 'someevent' ? 'someevent' : 'someotherevent';

     if(targetEvent) {
        document.addEventListeners('targetEvent', this.handleEvent);
     }
  }
  .....
}
```

Above is the sample code of my component.
I have written test cases for the component where as i am facing some difficulties in writing test case for one scenario described as below.

How to write test case for the below code

```
const targetEvent = getEvent() === 'someevent' ? 'someevent' : 'someotherevent';
```

getEvent() method is not a component instance method nor it's pass through.
How can the method be covered in the test case.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The question doesn't mention what's testing framework. Is it Jest? It should have respective tag then.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getEvent` is an import, it should be mocked. This is needed not only for the coverage but to isolate tested unit:

```
it('...', async () => {
  jest.mock('./utility', () => ({
    getEvent: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => 'someevent')
  });
  const MyComponent = (await import('...')).default;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @estus. Can you please elaborate a bit on this  const MyComponent = (await import('...')).default; How to write the assertion. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's dynamic import that should be used instead of `import MyComponent from ...` because it needs to be re-imported in the middle of the suite.. You can write the assertion as you would in any other case. If you test if `document.addEventListeners` was called then set up a stub and assert that it was called. The question doesn't specify which framework you use.